# Return asynchronous data from an angular method

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am fairly new to angular and am still trying to wrap my head around doing things the angular + httpClient + rxjs way. I am trying to write the rxjs equivalent of the following:

```
async onButtonClick = () => {
    const processedBooks = await this.getAndProcessBooks();
    await myGenericHttpClient.post('/api/something', processedBooks);
}

async getAndProcessBooks = () => {
    const books = await myGenericHttpClient.get('/api/books');

    const processedBooks = books.map(book => {
        return book.read = true;
    });

    return books;
};
```

My understanding of rxjs is i need to use angular's httpClient to make the request then subscribe to the response:

```
getAndProcessBooks = () => {
    return httpClient.get('/api/books').subscribe(books => {
        return books;
    });
};
```

However, the problem is `getAndProcessBooks` returns a subscription, not an array of books so I'm not sure how this method can return the data that I need. Any help or direction to resources would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - Return from subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61848091/angular-return-from-subscribe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the result from one API call and send it to another API call using the different map operators such as *mergeMap, concatMap*, etc of RxJs, which ever suits your use case.

I separated your HTTP calls and created functions for them just for easy readability.

```js
//Returns Books
getAndProcessBooks(): Observable<any> {
    return this.myGenericHttpClient.get('/api/books');
}

//API something that requires books to send call
apiSomethingFunction(processedBooks: any): Observable<any> {
   return this.myGenericHttpClient.post('/api/something', processedBooks);
}

//On the button click
 onButtonClick(): void {
    this.getAndProcessBooks()
      .pipe(
        switchMap((books) => {
          //Response of books comes here, you can map them before sending it to the something API
          return this.apiSomethingFunction(books);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
        console.log('I got Response of API Something');
      });
  }
```

The reason I used `switchMap` operator was to cancel the previous HTTP call if the user clicks on the button again. You can use different map if your use-case is different.

Comment: this should work, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could just take the observable and use it directly.

```js
unprocessedBooks$: Observable<any>;

getAndProcessBooks() {
    unprocessedBooks$ = httpClient.get('/api/books').pipe(data => {return data;});
};
```

And in html

```html
<div>{{ unprocessedBooks$ | async}}</div>
```

Comment: thanks @joosep - i made a slight change to my question in which i explain that i need to send the data to another endpoint, not show it in a template.